# Get Foreign Key objects in the query

Tags: django, api, rest

I have two models.
The first one represents different Projects with a name, an ID and a description
The second one is for tracking which user is in which Project.
So my models look like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Project(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(db_column = 'db_ID', primary_key = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default = None)
    descriptor = models.CharField(max_length = 1000, null = True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'projects'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name




class Userproject(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column = 'db_ID', primary_key = True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.SET_NULL, null = True)
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null = True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null = True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'UserProjects'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

In the Userproject there there is only the UserID and the ProjectID, both are ForeignKeys to the other models.

When I get a GET-Request with a username, I can get the userID , then I can filter all the Userprojects by the userID and serialize all those where the given user is present. But How would I include the Project data as well If I want to send the name of the Project as well?

Answer (score 1):

So you can run a query with power operators to filter data based on foreign object values.

```
user_projects = Userproject.objects.filter(user_id=user_id, project__name='yourproject')
```

Now to access project data from user_project you can use `.` operator.

```
if user_projects.exists():
    print(user_projects[0].user_id)
    print(user_projects[0].project.name)
    print(user_projects[0].project.descriptor)
```

To get values directly from the ORM, use `.values()`.

```
user_projects = Userproject.objects.filter(user_id=user_id, project__name='yourproject').values('project__name', 'project__descriptor)
```

This will fetch only the columns you specify as parameters.

Comment: I want to include the Project-modelfields in the queryset.
With this command, I would be only be able to filter the Userprojects by the Projectname right?

Comment: Later you can access Project's data  as described in answer.

Comment: Thank you! But I dont really get, How i could put it inside the queryset to send it back to the frontend.

Comment: Added another query for fetching only the required data values.